# How to apply shared dependencies in gradle kotlin dsl

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'am trying to migrate my Gradle Groovy into Kotlin dsl but I got an error on applying shared dependencies, I'm using multi module project.

```
apply from ("../shared_dependencies.gradle.kts")
```

I got function invocation apply() expected, but what does that mean?

Comment: `apply("../shared_dependencies.gradle.kts")` ?

Comment: Applying script plugins is documented here: https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/userguide/plugins.html#sec:script_plugins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple Kotlin way of achieving the same result is creating DependencyHandler extension functions within buildSrc module, e.g.:

```
fun DependencyHandler.applySharedDeps() {
    add("implementation", "com.some.dependency:version")
}
```

If you don't like the `add` method, you can create a further extension function:

```
private fun DependencyHandler.implementation(dependency: Any) {
    add("implementation", dependency)
}
fun DependencyHandler.applySharedDeps() {
    implementation("com.some.dependency:version")
}
```

Then you can simply call applySharedDeps in any module config:

```
dependencies {
    applySharedDeps()
}
```

If you also want to apply other configs, and not just dependencies, you can similarly create extension functions for other classes, even the Project class.

Comment: thanks sir, really appreaciate your help